# Coverity issue for deleting void pointer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, coverity

Coverity has pointed out a bug about deleting void pointer. The code is as below:

```
void *pbits=(void *)new char[((bmp.bmWidth*bitspixel+31)/32)*bmp.bmHeight*4];
result=GetDIBits(pDC->GetSafeHdc(),HBITMAP(*pbitmap),0,bmp.bmHeight,pbits,bitmapinfo,DIB_RGB_COLORS);

char curdir[100];
if(!GetCurrentDirectory(100,curdir))
{
    delete [] pbits;    
    return;
}
```

Can you please help me on what is incorrect and how can I solve it?

Many thanks

Best Regards

Chintan

Comment: Not sure why we have to guess at the warning it generates.  High odds it isn't too happy about you using delete[] on a void*.  So just don't use void*, a char* will work fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just use char* for the type of pbits.

Answer (score 0):

A `delete` on a `void *` is actually undefined; that's why the tool is reporting something. Just cast `pbits` when passing it to `GetDIBits` and you'll solve your issue.